# Querying across multiple Solr Instances, allowing for failure

Tags: solr, full-text-search, sharding

We are looking at building multiple Solr indexes, which will be dotted in different data centres and each will have the same Schema, but different data. We currently have a prototype of it working across 2 sites, and are adding more over the next few days... but if I kill the Solr instance on one of the boxes, and use the other with the shards option, adding that second box, I get a 500 Error message telling me the connection on the other machine is refused... What I am wondering is how do I get it to fail gracefully? Can I add something that, when one (or more) Solr indexes are MIA, I can tell users? Is this something built into Solr, or will I need to code around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature in Solr 4.0, named [shards.tolerant=true](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch). If a server does not respond, it will not kill the whole query, but instead add info to the header.